# The ring of additive polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I've come across the definition of additive polynomial (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_polynomial):

$F$ is a field of characteristic $p$, $P \in F[X]$ is a polynomial that satisfies $P(X) + P(Y) = P(X + Y)$. Than $P$ is called additive. It is claimed that P has a form
$$P(X) = \sum\limits_{i \geq0} a_i X^{p^I}, a_i \in F$$
While I agree that the polynomials of that form are additive, I couldn't come up with a proof to why all additive polynomials have that form. If you have an idea on how to approach this, please share.

Answer (score 0):

Since the equation $P(X) + P(Y) = P(X+Y)$ holds precisely if it holds in every degree, it is enough to look at homogeneous polynomials $aX^c$. If $c = 0$ it would be $a + a = a$, so $a = 0$. Let $c \geq 1$. Write $c = lp^i$ for some $1\leq l < p$. Then $a(X^{p^i}+Y^{p^i})^l = a(X+Y)^{lp^i} = a(X+Y)^c = a(X^c+Y^c)  = a((X^{p^i})^l+(Y^{p^i})^l)$. Since $F[X,Y] \cong F[X^{p^i},Y^{p^i}]$ it has to be $a(X+Y)^l = a(X^l+Y^l)$. Therefore $la(X+Y)^{l-1} = laX^{l-1}$. If $l> 1$, evaluating at $(0,1)$ gives $la = 0$ and then $a = 0$, since $1 < l < p$. So, $c = p^i$ or $a = 0$. This shows the claim.

Comment: Why is it enough to look at $P(X) = aX^c$? Could you expand a bit on that? Thats the part I don't quite get.

Comment: @ABlack If $f,g \in F[X,Y]$ then $f = g$ if and only if $f_k = g_k$ for all $k \geq 0$, where $f_k,g_k$ are the homogeneous summands of $f,g$ of degree $k$.

Comment: @psl2Z Answering duplicates is not encouraged. Standard questions usually are duplicates, and they can be easily found with site search (in this case, I added 2 of them, and there will be more).